# Как корректно настроить параметры Менеджера макетов?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, qt-designer

Не удается выставить параметры в Qt Designer.

ЗАДАЧА:

Черный и Серый виджеты должны менять размерность, сохраняя соотношения сторон 1х1, при увеличении/уменьшении главного окна. Габаритами зеленого окна можно пренебречь, ведь у него стоят минимальные размеры.

Я перепробовал разные сочетания параметров. Пока что у меня происходят изменения, но теряется соотношения сторон 2х виджетов. Я, что-то упускаю?

ПС: [S. Nick] надеюсь я учел ваши пожелания:)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ui:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>GcsWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="GcsWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1000</width>
    <height>630</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>1000</width>
    <height>630</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>GcsWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>1000</width>
     <height>630</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="sizeIncrement">
    <size>
     <width>1</width>
     <height>1</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="baseSize">
    <size>
     <width>1000</width>
     <height>630</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <property name="sizeConstraint">
     <enum>QLayout::SetDefaultConstraint</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="spacing">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_5">
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>16777215</width>
        <height>30</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="lineWidth">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
       <property name="spacing">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="leftMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="topMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="rightMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="bottomMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="BUT_Menu">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>80</width>
           <height>30</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>80</width>
           <height>30</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="baseSize">
          <size>
           <width>80</width>
           <height>30</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background-color: rgb(235,235,235);
    border-radius: 1px;
    Text-align:center;

}
QPushButton:hover{
    background-color:rgb(225, 225, 225);
}
QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
    border-style: inset;
}
QPushButton:open{
    background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
    border-style: inset;
}</string>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>MENU</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_UpperBar">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>40</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_all_widjets">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true"/>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="lineWidth">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
       <property name="sizeConstraint">
        <enum>QLayout::SetNoConstraint</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="leftMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="topMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="rightMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="bottomMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="spacing">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <item row="0" column="0">
        <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter_ver">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>0</width>
           <height>0</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeIncrement">
          <size>
           <width>0</width>
           <height>0</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="lineWidth">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="handleWidth">
          <number>1</number>
         </property>
         <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter_hor">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
            <horstretch>1</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>300</width>
            <height>0</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeIncrement">
           <size>
            <width>0</width>
            <height>0</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="baseSize">
           <size>
            <width>0</width>
            <height>0</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="handleWidth">
           <number>1</number>
          </property>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_one" native="true">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
             <horstretch>1</horstretch>
             <verstretch>1</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>300</width>
             <height>300</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeIncrement">
            <size>
             <width>0</width>
             <height>0</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="baseSize">
            <size>
             <width>1</width>
             <height>1</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(67, 67, 67);</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
          <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_two" native="true">
           <property name="sizePolicy">
            <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
             <horstretch>1</horstretch>
             <verstretch>1</verstretch>
            </sizepolicy>
           </property>
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>300</width>
             <height>300</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeIncrement">
            <size>
             <width>0</width>
             <height>0</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="baseSize">
            <size>
             <width>1</width>
             <height>1</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(176, 176, 176);</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </widget>
         <widget class="QWidget" name="widget_three" native="true">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>700</width>
            <height>0</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeIncrement">
           <size>
            <width>0</width>
            <height>0</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="baseSize">
           <size>
            <width>1</width>
            <height>1</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(85, 170, 127);</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Ничего не упускаете - просто так не получится для всех случаев,  а только если у окна высота будет меньше ширины. Кроме того, как мне кажется, еще придётся писать соответствующий код для коррекции размеров маленьких панелей. Короче, оно вам надо? Сколько лет работаю с Qt и ни разу такое не понадобилось. Какая у вас конечная цель?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, спасибо за ответ. Конечная цель - практика. Я такое видел вживую и решил попробовать воссоздать. Надеялся средств QtDesigner-а хватило бы, но понял, что придётся писать вручную :)